# Includegraphics doesn't show the figure. Overleaf v2

Tags: overleaf, includegraphics

I'm working on overleaf v2.

I wrote :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % Accents codés dans la fonte
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}  % Les traductions françaises
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{document}
....
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{comp_W_log.jpg}
\caption{\textit{On compare la fonction de Lambert à $\log(x)-1$ dans un certain interval}}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
 ....
\end{document}
```

But I just get, after compiling :
[image]

Can you help me plz ?

**Edit:** png didn't work either

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) always post full code, not sniplets. (3) It seems you have draft mode enabled, either as a class option or option to `graphicx`

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but better use `\log` instead of `log`

Comment: I don't know how exactly your image looks like, but from the caption I would guess that `jpg` is not a good file type for it. Better use a vector format like `pdf` or if you really have to use a pixelated format at least use `png`

Comment: Again unrelated to your problem, but don't load the same package multiple times and the option `frenchb` is deprecated, use `french` instead. For a French text it would probably also be good to load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. You probably want to give some floating specifier to your figure, e.g. `\begin{figure}[htbp]` for a better placement. And instead of manually changing the font family of your caption to italic, have a look at the caption package to make this automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your editor could be set to 'draft mode' on Overleaf (this skips compiling images to render a PDF faster). You can turn it off on the dropdown menu on the Recompile button:

[image: switch to 'normal mode' on recompile menu]

Hope this does the trick, if you still see issues it could be worth writing to Overleaf support, at support@overleaf.com (I work there)

Comment: So in V2 we either get a fast autocompiler or an autocompiler that loads images, even though V1 could do both?

Comment: @Melody Autocompile and fast mode can be turned on and off independently of each other, if that was the question? The standard compilation on v2 (with images rendered) is generally a bit faster than the same one on v1, but the caching of auxiliary files works a bit differently so some projects might be slower. If you're seeing a project compiling slower on v2 we should be able to help out if you write to us. On v1, the fast/draft setting also didn't show images. The setting is the same as passing the draft option to the documentclass.

Comment: I'm seeing all my code compile a lot slower in V2 with the normal compile mode. I really wish I could still use V1, but it seems disabled now. At least I don't know how to access it. Maybe it's because I have a really long preamble?