# How to place multiple pdf figures next to each other in Latex

Tags: floats, pdftex, subfloats

I have four charts which were originally in `eps` file format. I have exported them as `pdf`s and I am trying to include them next to each other and under each other.

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{testing}
\author{abc}
\date{}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{figure}%
    \centering
    \subfloat[label 1]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{mat_density_r1.pdf}}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[label 2]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{mat_density_r2.pdf}}%
    \newline
    \subfloat[label 1]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{mat_density_r3.pdf}}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[label 2]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{mat_density_r4.pdf}}%
    \caption{2 Figures side by side}%
    \label{fig:example}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have two issues:

1. I am not able to see the images
2. They are not aligned

[image: picture of rendering]

I am not getting any errors in overleaf and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Overleaf may not show images in draft mode !

Comment: I am an idiot. you are right. I didn't know what draft mode was. Thanks

Comment: for your image display issue see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470688/170109 you could remove that from your question so it is just positioning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are four problems here:

1. your used `\newline` is wrong here. Replace it simply with a blank line
2. you used option `[demo]` for package `graphicx`. Omit it.
3. you do not need package `epstopdf` here for your issue
4. I changed the double labels 1 and 2 to 3 and 4

So with the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{testing}
\author{abc}
\date{}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{figure}%
    \centering
    \subfloat[label 1]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[label 2]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-b}}%

    \subfloat[label 3]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-c}}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[label 4]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}}%
    \caption{2 Figures side by side}%
    \label{fig:example}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Replace `\newline` with `\\` and you will get what you want as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{testing}
\author{abc}
\date{}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \begin{figure}%
        \centering
        \subfloat[label 1]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}}%
        \qquad
        \subfloat[label 2]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}}%
        \\
        \subfloat[label 1]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}}%
        \qquad
        \subfloat[label 2]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}}%
        \caption{2 Figures side by side}%
        \label{fig:example}%
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which will give you:

[image]