# \includegraphics{picture} yields only a placeholder box

Tags: graphics, overleaf

Currenly my issue with `\includegraphics` is as follows: `\includegraphics{example.png}` results in the following picture even though the example.png picture is present in the same directory as the main.tex file in Overleaf. [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqqnN.png).

There is no error nor warning regarding the image name or path. Since e.g. the command: `\includegraphics{exampleasdf.png}` gives a warning that "*File 'exampleasdf.png' not found on line*", I am under the impression that the compiler finds the image file, but cannot read it? I changed my PDF viewer to native, but it did not resolve the issue. However, the exact same command in a dummy project gives out the desired output. [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNr9S.png).

If I could I would share the the relevant .tex code, but as it is part of my thesis that uses a ready-made-format, I don't know what is and what is not important to share. That is, I would end up sharing pages upon pages of .tex code. It could be that the fault lies in some ready-made setting, but what to look for?

Comment: The first thing is to check that you aren't compiling with Overleaf set to draft mode: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470688/21344

Comment: There are two modes, "draft" and "final".  In draft mode, only the name of the graphics files are shown, in order to save time.

Comment: @PaulGessler This was the issue, thanks!

Comment: note (for next time) you could easily have made an example to post here: starting from a copy of your thesis delete everything except the \includegraphics, then delete every package not used in the remaoning example, check the problem still occurs and post the resulting pne pag eexample.