inserting image in overleaf
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{graphics}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{Untitled.jpg}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

After running this code, it is not showing any image. Just a box with untitled.jpg written inside. How do I fix this?
Edit:
Okay, so let me say somethings more:

The file I uploaded was in my computer, and overleaf itself selected it from there.
Thus, it certainly exists in my computer and overleaf isn't showing any red errors.
it implies that my code is fine(?) but i don't get any image in the pdf, rather something I described above.
Many people in the comments said something about "draft" which I absolutely did not understand.

I hope any further answers will be helpful according to my edited question. Sorry for not clarifying these before. I am new to LaTeX and please help me in simple terms.
Thanks in advance.
Edit:
Here's the fun thing: When I ran the same code using the same procedure in another new page in Overleaf, the output was exactly how I wanted. but using the same in my text file, the image is not appearing. What is happening? Is it Overleaf's fault?
Here's a screenshot of a relevant page: I have removed the \begin{figure}...\end{figure} here but the output in both cases is the same.

Okay, I'm adding another image here:

Here's another image:


Never ignore errors. You get an error highlighted in red on Overleaf that Untitled.jpg is not found as there is no such file in the standard dostribution. graphics then falls back to draft mode that adds the filename in a box as you describe. But after any error the pdf output is just a debugging aid, not anything to be used.

So what do I do to fix this?

You probably should check if your image is indeed in the same level as your TeX main document. It seems is in a different directory level.

@FKcosθ you need to include an image that exists, eiether change the name of the image in the latex file, or upload an image called Untitled.jpg in to  your project.

please show the full .log file from your overleaf project. You can access it like this: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/View_generated_files

Is is listed in the project files on the left of the page.

whther a file is on your computer makes no diffeence to overleaf as it hs no access, what matters is whether you uploaded the file to your overleaf project. Please as requested show the full log from the document shown.

excuse me, is it this that you wanted? "Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 592--593"

That is not caused by the code you've shown, which only has 12 lines.  Please copy and paste the code you've shown into a new project, and upload you jpg file there as well.  And if you still don't have the image, I would recommend contacting Overleaf support.  Also, \usepackage{graphics} is the outdated version; you want \usepackage{graphicx}.  But I don't think that would cause this problem.

The image could not be shown because 1) it is not where LaTeX expects it to be (it should be in the working directory which is the upper hierarchy level in the file branch in Overleaf), 2) the file is broken, i.e. it is not a valid JPG file, 3) your real code is different from what you show and relevant commands are overwritten or defined in such a way that the image is not properly positioned (but I doubt that this is the case here). If you show the log file (for the above code it should not be too long, so you could post it completely by editing your question), we might be able to tell more.

No you should show the log I added the full log that I got on overleaf to my answer, you should do exactly the same, then people can compare why I get an error (and draft mode output) but you say you get draft mode output with no error.

In addition to the .log file, please also show a screenshot of the left sidebar of your overleaf project. If I remember correctly, overleaf has some option there, like fast mode or something similar, which will enable draft mode for graphics.

Well, actually my document is huge and the full log text is considerably large and exceeds the word limit here. So how do I post it here? Moreover, here's the fun thing: When I ran the same code in a new overleaf page, the output was exactly how I wanted, But running the same code and using same procedure, the picture is not appearing on the main document I'm working on.

Click on menu in the top left corner and show the left sidebar with the options for your project.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have edited my post. Is it this that you wanted?

@FKcosθ yes, thanks. Can you also click on the drop-down arrow next to the recompile button and show us a screenshot? https://i.sstatic.net/9nijZVzK.png

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Ok I have added it.

@FKcosθ Don't use the draft option if you want to see images (and fix the other 11 errors)

Probably a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470680/includegraphics-doesnt-show-the-figure-overleaf-v2/470688#470688

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks! my image is now working!!

@FKcosθ Fix all the other errors as well. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

This question is similar to: Includegraphics doesn't show the figure. Overleaf v2. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

LaTeX flags this as an error and Overleaf marks the error in its user interface:

As the text in the red box says, the graphics package falls back to draft mode (which just places the filename in a box) if the image is not found.
There is no Untitled.jpg in the standard TeXLive distribution so unless you uploaded such a file into your project, this error is expected.
The full log as copied from the overleaf page is
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.8.9)  13 DEC 2024 20:19
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count188
\c@section=\count189
\c@subsection=\count190
\c@subsubsection=\count191
\c@paragraph=\count192
\c@subparagraph=\count193
\c@figure=\count194
\c@table=\count195
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2024-03-14 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count196
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
) (./output.aux)
\openout1 = `output.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count197
\scratchdimen=\dimen141
\scratchbox=\box52
\nofMPsegments=\count198
\nofMParguments=\count199
\everyMPshowfont=\toks17
\MPscratchCnt=\count266
\MPscratchDim=\dimen142
\MPnumerator=\count267
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count268
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks18
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 485.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
))

LaTeX Warning: File `Untitled.jpg' not found on input line 9.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `Untitled.jpg' not found: using draft setting.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9     \includegraphics{Untitled.jpg}
                                      
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./output.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
 ***********
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1188 strings out of 474104
 19471 string characters out of 5743486
 1925493 words of memory out of 5000000
 23612 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558237 words of font info for 37 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 42i,5n,51p,160b,236s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb>
Output written on output.pdf (1 page, 20078 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 18 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 10 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)



I uploaded it as an image from my computer. It actually doesn't show any red errors in my document, but it isn't giving satisfactory outputs also

@FKcosθ as you showed no log or error description but described the expected draft mode output, I answered based on the information you provided. If an image is available but latex used draft mode without giving an error themn that should mean that you used [draft] in the document. but the document you showed did not use [draft]

@FKcosθ add in a code block the full log that you get from the document in your question
